# Why the facebook pixel tests well in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: security, facebook, google-chrome, firefox, tracking-pixel

I've a website with a facebook pixel via Tag Manager. I fire a "page view" FB event triggered on the "page view" tag manager event.

## In chrome

I then open the pixel tester on Chrome https://business.facebook.com/events_manager2/list/pixel/ and click on the `Test events` tab in firefox.

In the URL box I set my website and I click to check, a new broswer tab opens and immediately in the pixel tester I see a "page view".

**So it works in chrome.**

## In Firefox

Then I do exactly the same in Firefox.

And the event does not get logged.

**Seems to not work in Fiorefox.**

## Question

Is there any incomptaibility between the Facebook pixels and Firefox which does not reveal as a problem in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Firefox [blocks a lot of tracking](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-desktop) these days. It's probably not an incompatibility so much as a deliberate design choice.